# I have there is no resources error in my xml file

Tags: android, xml, mobile

I have an Android xml file that added to create a splash, for this splash I uploaded a image and  set xxhdpı, xhddi, mdpı, hdpı formats from nine patch then I added each one to each format (I mean xxhdpı to xxhdpı format and mdpı to mdpı format folder under resources) then it gives an error

```
no resources found the given name(at backround with value '@drawable tesbihsplashh.9.png'
```

Comment: Use `@drawable/tesbihsplashh` instead of `@drawable tesbihsplashh.9.png'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `Background` image like:

```
android:background="@drawable/tesbihsplashh"
```

Make sure `tesbihsplashh.png` image avialable into your `drawable` folder.